# Use auto-generated keys for Liferay Entities

Tags: liferay, primary-key, liferay-6, identity, liferay-service-builder

For my custom service entities build using Service-builder I can use the `identity-type` in `service.xml` so that my custom entity's primary key generation is handled by the underlying databases.

Is there a way I can have Liferay's entities to also use database's auto-generation instead of using a custom `Counter`?

<sub>**Note:** Cross posted on [Liferay forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56678608).</sub>